# Mac: why do I get error when I try to call osgeo in Python?

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo

I try to import `ogr` from `osgeo`

```
from osgeo import ogr
```

but I get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'
```

Before I installed `GDAL`, if I do:

```
pip3 install gdal
Requirement already satisfied: gdal in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.4.0)
```

Comment: `osgeo` is not part of the standard library. Have you installed it?

Comment: I installed `GDAL`

Comment: From the message you are getting it looks like that wasn't enough or did not work. Did the install of `GDAL` run correctly to completion without errors? When I try to install it I get a missing header file message and it appears this is common. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip which claims to be a fix.

Comment: @BoarGules yes I did `brew install gdal` and then `pip3 install gdal`

Comment: @BoarGules should I try to restart the mac?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling python 3 and not python 2?  That's a constant issue on mac.

Comment: actually I am running it also on `jupyter` and the kernel is python 3

Comment: @cdarke is this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Before running `pip3 install gdal`, try installing [the complete GDAL package for Mac from this site](https://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks/).